# Changing new lines characters to Linux format

Tags: linux

I have downloaded source code for some software from svn on Linux and want to build it:

```
$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Character ^M is a \r carriage return character. When I change line ending of files to Linux format then it starts to work, however there are many of these files and it is manually hard to do. How to change line endings in all files in directory and its subdirectories to Linux format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make dos2unix convert each file in the directory.

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dos2unix for this (which might be in a package called "tofrodos"), this changes the file in-place.

```
dos2unix input
```

Or if you want to do it really simple, you can delete all \r from your file with tr.

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will find all files ending with "*.sh" and call [`dos2unix`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dos2unix) on them to convert line endings:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

To find all files, pass `-type f` to `find` without specifying `-name` parameter. See [A Unix/Linux find Command Tutorial](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like dos2unix/unix2dos, older tools were fromdos/todos.